# Emf within a square loop

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Will the Emf induced be same

**Case 1 :** when a square sheet is moved in a constant magnetic field.

**Case 2 :** when a square frame is moved in a constant magnetic field.

I am assuming the material(metal) and dimensions, the velocity of both cases to be the same.

What happens inside the square sheet of metal moving through a constant magnetic field or inside the metal of the square frame. Let's assume the sheet and frame move perpendicular to the magnetic field, so an equilibrium state will develop.

Comment: You can consider square loop elements of thickness dx.(and integrate if required? In each of these(and in case 1) the net emf induced in the loop cancels from a opposite sides by symmetry and it would be 0.